# Key-based cache expiration

Tags: caching

I'd like to discuss post on 37signals blog named [How key-based cache expiration works](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works). I'm Django developer, not RoR, so here is Django "translation" by Ross Poulton: [Key-based cache expiration with Django](http://www.rossp.org/blog/2012/feb/29/fragment-caching/).

As you can see, main idea is following: we have "russian-doll" structure, where one object contains several levels of other.

```
class A:
  timestamp updated_at;

class B:
  A parent;
  timestamp updated_at;

class C:
  B parent;
  timestamp updated_at;
```

View (for example, HTML) of object of class A is cached with all related objects. When class C is updated, we need:

1. Update timestamp in C.
2. Update timestamp in B.
3. Update timestamp in A.

When we access view of class A after this, we need:

1. Make SELECT to get timestamp from A.
2. Check, that there is no cached object with this timestamp, so we
   need to recache it.
3. Make SELECT to get A data.
4. Make SELECT to get all timestamps from B.
5. Get Bs exist in cache.
6. Make SELECT to get Bs that not exists in cache.
7. Make SELECT to get all timestamps of Cs related with Bs that not
   exist in cache.
8. Get Cs from cache, if exist.
9. Make SELECT to get Cs that not exist in cache.

So, if I understand this strategy right, we need to do 6 queries to DB - 2 for each object: one will get timestamps, second - objects, outdated in cache.

Instead, if we will reset all data, we need to make only 3 queries:

1. Get object A.
2. Get related objects B.
3. Get related objects C.

As I know, it's ofter better to execute 3 queries with more data instead of 6 queries with less. So is this strategy effective?

Of course, we can store timestamps in cache too, but in this case we will face with problem of invalidation of timestamp. So it's no sense to invalidate data for strategy that needed to avoid invalidation.

Please, correct me if I wrong in understanding of scope or principle of work of this algorithm.

Comment: I've recently built something similar to this in Java.  In your example, are A, B, and C the cache keys or the cached objects?

Comment: @arootbeer, it's classes. All instances of these classes are cachable.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you're essentially asking

"Doesn't this strategy make it more expensive to load an entry when there is a cache miss?"

Which is a valid question, but I think it misses the point of caching: if you do it right, your misses are rare enough that a more expensive load process is offset by the cheapness of doing many cache lookups.

If my understanding is correct, let me know and I'll put in a more thorough answer.

Comment: @arootbeer, I think, that this caching strategy makes sense in one case, but in other not. For example, if we have one simple object that includes another, seems, it doesn't make sense. So my question is when it does. For my opinion, it's only if we have "russian-doll" structure with many levels and objects on each level and multiple cached fragments that represent one parent or child object. I'm trying to understand, what is the cases when this strategy helps me. Besides, DB touching on the each request confuses me.

Comment: I understand now.  I'll have to do a bit more digging to see exactly what it's doing, but as I'm trying to learn RoR anyway it should be a useful exercise.